# How to use Facebook Connect in an iPhone webapp

Tags: iphone, facebook, web-applications

I'm trying to use Facebook Connect from an iPhone **webapp**, so it would look similar to how it looks in a native iPhone app which is using the Facebook Connect iPhone SDK.

The iPhone SDK gets the nice login page by visiting:

```
http://www.facebook.com/login.php?fbconnect=1&connect_display=touch&api_key=<key>&next=fbconnect://success
```

(see http://github.com/facebook/facebook-iphone-sdk/blob/master/src/FBLoginDialog.m)

Since I don't want Safari to open, the only way I see to show this page is by using an iframe.

Then there's the problem of detecting success and failure.

The SDK can do this by simply using the `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:` delegate method and checking for `fbconnect://success` and `fbconnect://cancel`.

As far as I know, the parent page cannot monitor the URL of the iframe.

I could open a Comet connection to a server from the parent page and have Facebook redirect to my server, which would then notify the parent page on success. But I don't like the idea of intruducing a server component to my webapp just because of this.

Does anyone have any clever ideas?

**Edit: This is about a *web-app*, not a native app.**

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? Have the same problem with OpenID and would be interested to see what you came up with. Thx!

Comment: I was actually about to post this exact same problem. I didn't think of putting it in an iframe -- that's a great idea.

Answer (score 1):

OK so just a small test, but I tried this out:

```
var iframe = $("<iframe src='http://google.com'></iframe");
$("body").append(iframe);
$("body").find("iframe:last").attr("src"); // => http://google.com
```

And it seemed to work OK. I had this same problem so I'm going to try this same solution tonight in my app.  I don't want to do an interval that constantly checks the SRC, so I'll see if I can trigger an event on change of that SRC.

Also an alternative to dealing with Comet is WebSockets.  A nice, easy to deal with service is [PusherApp](http://www.pusher.com) (which I already am using in my app anyway), so if I can't figure out how to trigger an event once the iframe SRC attribute changes, I'll probably just push a "auth_succeeded" event to the client and handle it that way.

Thanks for the iframe idea. I was wondering how I would support FB Connect in an iPhone webapp without spawning a Safari window and taking them out of my app.

Comment: The src of the iframe will not change.

Answer (score 1):

```
To use facebook from your app just download FBConnect and drag and drop all files of FBConnect to your project.Make sure copy the files in project option is checked.After adding files make your .h file in which you have to share something like this

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "cocos2d.h"
#import "Facebook.h"
#import "FBConnect.h"


@interface GameOverPage :CCLayer<FBSessionDelegate,FBDialogDelegate,FBLoginDialogDelegate,FBRequestDelegate>
{

 //for sharing
    BOOL isFBLogged;
    Facebook *facebook;
}


after this add following delegate  methods to .m file.To use facebook just call [self facebookLogin];



- (void) facebookLogin
{   
//  App ID
//    ****************
//    
//    App secret
//    *****************************   

    if (facebook == nil) {
        facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"**********************"];
        NSLog(@"reached in if facebook nill");
    }   


NSArray* permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                              @"publish_stream", @"offline_access", nil] retain];

    [facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];

    // If you want to add Logout capability:
    if (isFBLogged) {
        NSLog(@"in isFBLogggged");
        [facebook logout:self];
    }
    //  } else { // then the code above inside the else
}
-(void) postdata
{
    UIImage *facebookimage=[self takeScreenShot];
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   facebookimage,@"message",                                   
                                   nil];

    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"  //  use page ID instead of 'me'
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
    NSLog(@"Uploading screenshot. Please wait...");
}

- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSLog(@"in fbDidLogin");
    isFBLogged = YES;   
    [self postdata];

}
-(void)fbDidNotLogin:(BOOL)cancelled {
    if (cancelled) {

        NSLog(@"LOGIN CANCELLED");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"login error");

    }

    //self.visible = YES;
}
- (void)fbDidLogout {
    NSLog(@"in fbDidLogOut");
    isFBLogged = NO;
    //-facebookLoginButton.visible = YES;
    //-facebookLogoutButton.visible = NO;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark FBRequestDelegate
/**
 * Called when the Facebook API request has returned a response. This callback
 * gives you access to the raw response. It's called before
 * (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result,
 * which is passed the parsed response object.
 */
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

}

/**
 * Called when a request returns and its response has been parsed into
 * an object. The resulting object may be a dictionary, an array, a string,
 * or a number, depending on the format of the API response. If you need access
 * to the raw response, use:
 *
 * (void)request:(FBRequest *)request
 *      didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
 */
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didLoad:(id)result {   


    NSLog(@"posted");
};

/**
 * Called when an error prevents the Facebook API request from completing
 * successfully.
 */
- (void)request:(FBRequest *)request didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {    

    NSLog(@"an error occured");

};

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark FBDialogDelegate

/**
 * Called when a UIServer Dialog successfully return.
 */
- (void)dialogDidComplete:(FBDialog *)dialog {
    NSLog(@"publish successfully");
}

you can override all delegate methods according to your requirement or leave the same way they are.This will work fine.You should have appid of facebook which you will get after registration on Facebook.
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be able to accomplish this through OAuth 2.0.  Facebook documentation is pretty thin--there's a nice discussion of it over at http://www.raywenderlich.com/1488/how-to-use-facebooks-new-graph-api-from-your-iphone-app

That blog post is about using OAuth and the new Graph API within an iPhone app, but I found the OAuth discussion to be better than anywhere else.  You may be able to use the URLs and flow he discusses within your webapp to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a mobile web app, on iOS and Android, with all the Facebook connectivity. Granted, it was all hosted on the server and not deployed on the iOS device as a web app.

The basic idea was: use the FB Javascript SDK to load the dialog for login/logout, handle the result on the server as "is logged in" (display something) vs. "is not logged in" display error message or non-logged in content.

In reference iFrames - which I've also done for FB apps, but on canvas not in Web mobiel- you link out to the login url as "_top", and incoming, you redirect back into the iFrame (give it a name) with various signed_request data. So yes, there is server scripting there to handle the logged in/logged out status (if that's what you were referring to above).

Answer (score 0):

just try this

http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/381270-addthis-for-ios-quick-start-guide#.T5Yz-1FRr9A

and

http://socialize.github.com/socialize-sdk-ios/getting_started.html#id2

Answer (score -1):

Using Sharekit is a good option until you just wanna move out of the problem. As it provides ready made classes for you. Simply calling methods would be sufficient even for other social networking sites as well like Twitter. Moreover, you can add your custom methods to it as per your need.

Answer (score -1):

You can either use each social networks API individually, or you can use [ShareKit](http://www.getsharekit.com/)